# Define a multi interface Variable

Tags: java, variables, interface

I want to define a variable that implement 2 interface.
Imove and Ijump are 2 interface.

```
class b implements Imove,Ijump {...}
class a implements Imove,Ijump {...}
Imove,Ijump player = new a();
Imove,Ijump player = new b();
player.Jump();
player.Move();
```

Comment: You refer to the object instance either by it's class or **one** of the interfaces it implements, e.g. `a player = new a();` or `Imove player = new a();` etc

Comment: Alternatively, if you need something that is `Imove` and `Ijump`, you could create an `interface Imoveandjump extends Imove, Ijump {}` and use this. --- Some remarks on your code: class-, interface- and enum-names should always be written in `CamelCase` (`a` -> `A`, `Imove` -> `IMove`, `Ijump` -> `IJump`), while methods should be written in `camelCase` (`Jump()` -> `jump()`, `Move()` -> `move()`) --- In general, interfaces should not be prefixed (`Imove` -> `Move`, `IJump` -> `Jump`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

interface can inherit from (multiple) other interface with extends.

Define third interface.

```
interface MoveAndJump extends IMove,IJump{};
```

Use that third interface.

```
MoveAndJump player = new a();
player.jump();
player.move();
```